# How do i retrieve data from a input element with javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to get data from a input element/textarea and it for some reason isn't getting it, and new errors keep popping up, i've tried using on click, i've tried adding an eventlistener, i've tried retriving the elements in a different way but nothing seems to be working.

HTML:

```
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/login.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>

    <div class="heading">
        <div class="heading-image"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="200" height="200" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-shield-lock-fill" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
            <path  fill-rule="evenodd" d="M8 0c-.69 0-1.843.265-2.928.56-1.11.3-2.229.655-2.887.87a1.54 1.54 0 0 0-1.044 1.262c-.596 4.477.787 7.795 2.465 9.99a11.777 11.777 0 0 0 2.517 2.453c.386.273.744.482 1.048.625.28.132.581.24.829.24s.548-.108.829-.24a7.159 7.159 0 0 0 1.048-.625 11.775 11.775 0 0 0 2.517-2.453c1.678-2.195 3.061-5.513 2.465-9.99a1.541 1.541 0 0 0-1.044-1.263 62.467 62.467 0 0 0-2.887-.87C9.843.266 8.69 0 8 0zm0 5a1.5 1.5 0 0 1 .5 2.915l.385 1.99a.5.5 0 0 1-.491.595h-.788a.5.5 0 0 1-.49-.595l.384-1.99A1.5 1.5 0 0 1 8 5z"/>
          </svg></div>
        <div class="heading-title">Sign In To PrivDono</div>
        <div class="heading-text">Please confirm your phone number. No dashes.</div>
    </div>


    <div class="form-container">
    <form onsubmit="return false" id="phoneForm">
        <input type="tel" id="phoneInput" name="phone" pattern="[0-9]{3}[0-9]{3}[0-9]{4}" required>
        <button class="form-submit">NEXT</button>
    </form>
</div>
<script src="/js/validation.js" defer></script>
</body>

</html>
```

JS:

```
window.onload = function () {

    const form = document.getElementsByClassName("form-submit")[0];
    console.log(form)

    if (form) {

        form.onclick(event => {
            event.preventDefault();

            
            const number = document.getElementById('phoneInput');

            

            console.log(number, number.value);
        })


    };






};
```

Comment: form.onClick is the wrong event. Use form.onSubmit event

Comment: actually it should be `form.onclick = (event) => {}` because you are setting the function value not invoking it.. anyway form it's not a form but a button that's why the click event instead of the submit event. And that was the main reason the code was breaking. Everything else is just oversaying

Answer (score 0):

this way...
in a form there is allways **name** attributes...

```js
const formPhone = document.forms.phoneForm;

formPhone.onsubmit = evt =>
  {
  evt.preventDefault();
  console.log( formPhone.phone.value );
  }
```

```html
<form name="phoneForm">
  <input type="tel" name="phone" pattern="[0-9]{3}[0-9]{3}[0-9]{4}" required>
  <button class="form-submit">NEXT</button>
</form>
```